# How to add value for a specific object?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Good day all, I have this question which is a headache for me. I'll try to break this down as specific as I can

- On the backend which is Laravel, I have this **Facts** table which has **type** and **text** but on my application it has 3 different fields

[image]

- So in front-end it should be something like this

facts: [{"type":"engine_size", "text":"User Input"}]

- Here's my code on the app:

```
 state = {
   controls: {
     facts: [{ type: "", text: "" }],
   },
 };


   <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
           <Text style={{ color: "white", marginTop: 10 }}> Engine Size 
           </Text>
           <IconInputField
             value={this.state.controls.facts.map(item => ({
               type: "engine_size",
               text: item.text
             }))}
             onChange={this.factsAddedHandler}
             icon={require("../../assets/img/motor.png")}
           />
         </View>
```

- Can you please give me like a hint or how I can structure this? I appreciate it. Btw, there's a reason why it should be structured like that and it's a long story so I can't do anything else to have it acted different.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the array into object

```js
const facts = [{"type":"engine_size", "text":"User Input"}];
const newFacts= facts.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => (accumulator[currentValue.type] = currentValue.text, accumulator), {});

console.log(newFacts)
```

then create an object mapping for image like this:

```
const images = {
  engine_size: "../../assets/img/motor.png"
  ...
}
```

make sure you know exactly what data returns from api look like as "engine_size" is hardcode
.then you could access your data like below

```
<IconInputField
  value={newFacts["engine_size"]}
  onChange={this.factsAddedHandler}
  icon={require(images["engine_size"])}
/>
```